# is there a way to eval a piece of php code where die() or exit() is present and return to main code if it is called?

Tags: php, error-handling, exit, die

I do not have control over the code I'm executing. This is a third party function, but not user-entered. These are things that are versioned so it is impractical that I poke there and change all die()'s into something more sane. Because a new version is coming from time to time and then I could paradoxically make the code even more insecure by trying mess with it poor error handling.

so let's say we have a function:

```
fuction myfunc() {
  // lot's of complicated code
  if (!is_file('myfile.txt') exit('file not found');
  // and so on
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to somewhat run that piece of code and return to my main thread and then act accordingly with that error.

I've tried `die()` or `eval()` but this returns the whole script.
Bummer ?

Comment: Could you use this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

Comment: @markdwhite: not really because this is a pretty complicated thing, it calls another functions and objects, and there are changes in every version, and I pretty do not have right to poke in directory of that code and change things there, it connects to the db, so if I mess something that won't be pretty.

Comment: If that thing is actually supposed to be used as a library then it should never ever do such braindead error handling. Are you talking about hypothetical cases, or actual problems you've had with this? There really are a ton more things you should be worried about that any unvetted code can mess up, not sure why you specifically focus on `die`. Testing the library before rolling it out to production seems the only realistic option.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do when die/exit is called, you might be able to make use of [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function).

Comment: @deceze: it's an library used on intranet let's say in some firm, it is insecure as (I wont be using slurs here) but hopefully no one outside has access to it, there are three versions in production and going top to bottom if initializing one fails the code should fall back and try to setup an older one.

Comment: It sounds like this is really asking for a solution other than a technical workaround. My condolences.

Answer (score 3):

A Hail Mary approach is to use [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php)'s `runkit_function_redefine` or [`function_override`](http://php.net/override_function) to redefine the functions `die` and `exit` to throw an Exception instead.
A potential problem is that the 3rd party can catch those exceptions and might not deal with them correctly. It's also very likely that you can't properly deal with the exception either.

You can use [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function) to run code after `exit` has been called. You are somewhat limited in what you can do at this point as some services have already been shut down (such as autoloading). I think you can still output content, not sure about sessions and other headers.

Another approach would be to run the code in a seperate php process (or http request), for instance by calling php through [`exec`](http://php.net/exec).

A more solid approach can be to add predicitions to your own code, ensuring the bad states are never reached when calling the 3rd party code. It is possible that not all preconditions can be met.

Ideally only code that is an entry point (like a router script) may `exit`. Using `exit` anywhere else is just shoddy programming really.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not read [Halcyon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33784944/967748), you should have a look at it first.

Since you mention `eval()`, I assume you have the code as a string. I will refer to both `die()` and `exit()` by just the latter, but things should be relevant for both.

You can try and replace occurrences of die() and exit() with something, and then eval. It's simple but that can be very messy.

One thing to look out for, IF you decide to do this, is that you may end up replacing occurrences which are not really 'code'. For example, `echo "Let him exit()";`.

Also, when you consider possible equivalent syntax, like `exit   ();` , `exit;` or `exit(1);`, it gets much more unpleasant. You'll have to handle those with a regex.

But if you can safely assume that

1. those two signatures (`die()` and `exit()`) are the only ones you need to worry about; and
2. that strings (or other content) are not going to contain those 'phrases'

then you can use this approach.